# Regex to match '#attribute value' or 'attribute value' of linux configuration files but not '# a comment'

Tags: python, regex, linux

Linux has these configuration files like sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
#A b
#Port 1234
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

I'm writing a simple python regex code to identity the lines commented that does not have a space after the `#` (so they're not really comments) but also the noncommented lines, like `attribute value`. It's been hard writing this regex. I tried to start with:

```
#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

that is, the comment symbol is optional, but I need to match a word with 1 or more letters (the attribute), followed by another word with one or more letters (the value). But note that in:

```
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
```

it will match `Use these`, which is not what I want to do. I searched about `(?=)`, that will match what its before it, only if its followed by this condition, however I didn't suceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a `^` at the beginning of your regex so it only matches at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead assertion:

```
re.findall('^(?!#\s).*', s, re.MULTILINE)
```

For input given int the question it will provide following output:

```
['',
 '#A b',
 '#Port 1234',
 '#ListenAddress ::',
 '#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0',
 'Protocol 2',
 'HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key',
 'HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key',
 'HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key']
```

**Update** [*Negative lookahead assertation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) matches only if next characters don't match. So in above `^` matches to beginning of line because `re.MULTILINE` is used. Then `(?!#\s)` matches everything except `#` character immediately followed by whitespace character. See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/C5tuh2/1).

Comment: How exactly yhis regex works? Matches anything that does not start with # and a space? And that has any character except line breaks in front of it?

Comment: @Gatonito Added short explanation, hope it helps